# MediaProjectionManagerService internally throws DeadObjectException

Tags: android, exception, warnings, android-mediaprojection

I have used the Media projection API to capture the screen.

I am getting the below warning while stopping the media projection.

```
10-07 10:32:57.394      537-537/? W/MediaProjectionManagerService﹕ Failed to notify media projection has stopped
    android.os.DeadObjectException
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
            at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
            at android.media.projection.IMediaProjectionCallback$Stub$Proxy.onStop(IMediaProjectionCallback.java:75)
            at com.android.server.media.projection.MediaProjectionManagerService$ClientStopCallback.run(MediaProjectionManagerService.java:614)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:269)
            at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:170)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

This is just a warning. Not a exception. Kindly help me to get out of this.

Comment: Did you use MediaProjectionManagerService in your application? If so how did u manage to do that? Can you please your code snippet here?

Answer (score 2):

According to the Android issue tracker, this issue had been fixed for the future release (at least, for Android M Preview 3 and later).

Yet, I'm not sure about backporting of this fix for Android Lollipop.

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81152
- https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2668

Comment: But I am not getting this now in lollipop, But before while developing i got this error log.